# My program always stops working :S (C++)

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I made a program to get data from a file, it works, but then the program says it stopped working.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string show()
{
    FILE *in;
    char c;
    in = fopen("version.txt", "r");
    if(in != NULL)
    {
        while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) 
        {
            putchar(c); 
        }
        fclose(in);
    }
    else printf("Unable to open file\n");
}


int main()
{
    show();
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger to step through your code. I can't spot anything inherently wrong with the code. (Unless you count `main()` which should be `main(int, char**)`).

Comment: @Jared Given that there is no `return` statement in either of the two functions, I suggest you to refresh C++ basics before going to a bit complex topics like file reading.

Comment: Why do you use `fopen`/`fgetc`/`fclose` and not `fstream`?

Comment: This isn't C++. It's C through and through. You do have a function that supposedly returns a `std::string` (a C++ concept), but nothing is returned by the function (the code shouldn't compile) and the return value isn't used.

Comment: @RedX It's absolutely legal and well defined for main to take no parameters.

Comment: Did you pay attention to *any* of the warnings that your compiler gave you?

Comment: @Mahesh, `main` without return implicitly returns 0; and even if `show()` is declared as `string show()`, he doesn't use the returned value... nor many of the C++ features, sticking to "C with `std::string`".

Comment: It compiled perfectly..? I am using dev-cpp.

Comment: What does it mean (in plain English) "the program says it stopped working"? What did exactly it said? Please post the exact text of any error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is declared to return a `string` but there is no return statement.
This is "undefined behavior" in C++ (only in `main` you are allowed to omit the return statement and in that case C++ will assume a `return 0;` automatically - but IMO it's nicer to also always write it).

Comment: How did the compiler not complain about that? I know Visual Studio does, at least in easily determinable cases like this one.

Comment: Additionally, main() does not have a return statement.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Indeed in many g++ doesn't complain about it and we got a few problems because of that. Note that technically a compiler is not **required** to inform you about this error.

Comment: @Aragangion: `main` in C++ is a (weird) exception. The `return` statement from `main` can be legally omitted (even if in my opinion is bad style).

Comment: i added the return: 0; at the end of main, and my problem still exists. sorry if i am mis-understanding your answer.

Comment: @Jared: it's the function `show` that must have a `return` statement because it's declared to return a `string`. If you don't need that then declare the function with `void` instead.

Comment: @6502 I have tried both of your suggestions, and my program is outputting that it is requesting the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way? Thank you though :)

Comment: @Jared: You didn't try a `return 0;` inside `string show()`, did you? You should return a string, since that's what you promised. Try `return "Return string from show()";` . From `int main()`, you can return 0 because that's an int.

Answer (score 1):

fgetc man says:

`fgetc() reads the next character from  stream  and  returns  it  as  an
       unsigned char cast to an int`

When your loop reaches the end of the file, `fgetc` returns EOF, which is on a int. As you cast it to a char, your condition will always return true. You must change the type of c to an int before testing if its value is EOF.

Comment: I changed char c; to int c; and my problem still exists... ty for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must return some string, for example return "";

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `string show()` to `void show()`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this did not solve my problem :(

Comment: Remove #include <windows.h>. It works fine on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of wrong or fuzzy things here.

First: decide if this has to be C or C++. In C++ there are other methods to read files (see `std::fstream`)

Second: remove not needed headers. Including both stdio and iostream (that make similar things, one for C the other for C++, means having a non clear idea of what you're actually want to do!)

Third: including windows.h means compile all the windows API declarations. That you're not using at all! What was the purpose of that?

Fourth: What's the purpose to `string`in `show`? string is a C++ type, in a program where all input had been written in C. And you didn't return anything!

Fifth: `fgetc` return as int. You're most likely running into the [EOF pitflall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getchar#EOF_pitfall).